# Inserting space between quotation mark and content

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Currently, I have a long list of educational institutions with their names in quotes. The list was compiled by many people so formatting isn't coherent. I am trying to make the entire list Title Case but the change case plugin is stuttering if I have a letter right after a quotation mark ;

i.e. If the content looks like this - "A

instead of - " A

The plugin makes it lowercase.

So in order to solve this issue I need to find a way to insert a space after every quotation mark in the list/ a space after every first quotation mark on every row.

Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: What plug in are you referring to? Can't you just use the `PROPER` function?

Comment: @Gravitate a plugin called "Change Case" as, I was unaware of the PROPER function, but it also did the job for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In one cell formula

> Use this **formula** to get rid of quotation marks and get names in [`PROPER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094133?hl=en) form, Take a look at the [**Example Sheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B4qb8M0LlXBIWu9mZDJBmczoVG3itrJX3iqE25-wqoQ/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A,CHAR(34),""))))
```

[image]

Functions used

[`PROPER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094133?hl=en)
[`SUBSTITUTE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215?hl=en)

Comment: ...and there is **no need for a plugin**. Nice :)

Answer (score 1):

You may try `SUBSTITUTE()` function like-

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(34),CHAR(34)&" ",1)
```

[image]